# How do I find the source of a repeating fault in the System Log in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-event-log

Every second I get the following fault in the system log in Windows 7. How do I find the source of this error and eliminate it?

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7000</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-04-27T09:38:50.676687100Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>9732594</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="924" ThreadID="6236" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>dr-satellite</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">msrvc</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">%%2</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Found it.

Searched for "msrvc" in the registry, and it pointed to "C:\Program Files (x86)\ssrvc\msrvc.exe:*:Enabled:USB aware Client".

I ended up installing (then uninstalling) "USB Lock" from Advanced Systems International a while ago. This program was so incredibly badly designed that its still monkeying with my home PC, 6 months later. I had to reboot into safe mode then delete the rogue files that it was infesting my system with.

Update:

Ended up reinstalling Windows to get rid of that buggy app. My advice? Don't touch it, unless you're into that suffering thing.